# How to run all JUnit tests in a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I am trying to generate a code coverage report of my Spring Boot application but am facing some issues with running all the existing unit tests at once.

Currently, I have quite a number of test classes (~20+) and when run individually on IntelliJ, they work fine with no issues or exceptions. However, when I create a JUnit configuration that builds and runs from "All in directory", 70-80% of my test classes fail and throws the same exception `IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

The stack trace seem to suggest some issues with the dependency injection. It follows this pattern:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ...
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'foo': Injection of resource dependencies
> failed; org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'bar': FactoryBean threw exception on object
> creation org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'foobar': Initialization of bean failed;

I'm not sure if this has something to do with the @SpringBootTest annotation which is repeated throughout all the test classes (I'm thinking maybe it's spinning up the application / context multiple times resulting in this issue?)

I think perhaps I'm doing it wrongly or have configured some annotations wrongly? How can I run all the JUnit test classes on IntelliJ?

P.S Sorry for the lack of context as it's not a personal project and I have to hide some information, and also I'm very new to SpringBoot and JUnit.

Comment: Are few of the test cases dependent? Or using resources from properties or yml file? Try to assign priority or sequence in JUnit test cases if they are running well independently ! As per the error, it seems few of the test cases are executing before your beans are created or so

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE in the folder structure go to test/java <-- right click and then click "Run test in java" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENoLx.png).
This is how I run all the tests in IntelliJ.

I don't know about the error you mention, but the times I've gotten a similar error is because I needed to set up environment variables. If that's the case instead of click on "Run test in java" go to "More Run/Debug --> Modify Run Configuration" and there set your environment variables in the corresponding field.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4zyC.png)